# MYSQL usng derived value in select multiple times

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to do something like the following?

```sql
select a as res, res * 2 as res2, res2 * 4 from tableA;
```

The instance I want to do this is much more complicated and it would make the query much more manageable if there was a way to not have to duplicate logic.

I was thinking a function would work but then I would not have the row by row action that the select allows for.

```sql
SELECT
    comp.playerID,
    comp.RC,
    comp.RC / (t.BPF + 100) / 200
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            playerID,
            coalesce(
                (sum(H) + sum(2B) + (2 * sum(3B)) + (3 * sum(HR))) + ((sum(BB) + sum(HBP) - sum(IBB)) * 0.26) - (sum(SH) + sum(SF) + sum(SB)) * 0.52,
                0
            ) AS RC
        FROM
            Batting
        GROUP BY
            playerID
    ) AS comp,
    Teams t;
```

There are a few nested layers outside of this, but this is the root of the duplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't refer to an alias in the same SELECT list. You need to use a subquery.

```
SELECT res, res * 2, res * 8
FROM (
    SELECT a AS res
    FROM tableA
) AS x
```

In your larger query, you're getting a full cross product between `comp` and `teams`, so you're duplicating each player on each team. You need to join the tables based on the player's team.

```
SELECT
    comp.playerID,
    comp.RC,
    comp.RC / (t.BPF + 100) / 200
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            playerID,
            teamID,
            coalesce(
                (sum(H) + sum(2B) + (2 * sum(3B)) + (3 * sum(HR))) + ((sum(BB) + sum(HBP) - sum(IBB)) * 0.26) - (sum(SH) + sum(SF) + sum(SB)) * 0.52,
                0
            ) AS RC
        FROM
            Batting
        GROUP BY
            playerID
    ) AS comp
JOIN Teams t ON comp.teamID = t.teamID
```

You didn't post your schema, so I had to guess at how the tables are related. You should be able to adjust the answer to the actual relationship (e.g. if there's a join table that relates players to teams, add another join).

Comment: @UUeerdo This seems to work however the primary key (that im getting in the deepest call with group by) is duplicated and only the first is used for all enclosing calls.

Comment: You're going to have to show something closer to what you're actually doing in the question.

Comment: Posted. The snippet shown is within a few subqueries but its the root of the duplication of the playerID primary keys. All rows have the same key but are correct other than that.

Comment: You're missing a joining condition between `comp` and `t`, so you're getting a full cross product.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an alias from the SELECT clause anywhere but the ORDER BY, GROUP BY HAVING clauses; not even elsewhere in the SELECT clause. However, you can (and must) reference the, in outer queries, so you can do something like this:

```
SELECT res, res2, res2 * 4
FROM (
   SELECT res, res * 2 AS res2
   FROM (
      SELECT a AS res
      FROM table A
   ) AS a2
) AS a3
```

Note, chaining like this more than once or twice can get a bit unwieldy as there must be a layer of subquery for each step in the equation.